# Align text to right of Image

Tags: html, css

I'd like to align all 3 lines of text to the right of my image. Currently it wraps on the 2nd line.

How do I do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/bhu4p04r/

**CSS:**

```
img {
    min-width:75px;
    height:90px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-right:30px
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="medium-12 columns"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/75/90" />1<br />2<br />3</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your text in a div, and make image `float:left`.

```
<div class="medium-12 columns">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/75/90" class="left" />
    <div class="right">1
        <br />2
        <br />3</div>
</div>
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/bhu4p04r/4/)

**Vertically middle text:**

Give `display:inline-block;` to image and the text container.

```
img, .text {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle
}
```

[**See DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hiral/bhu4p04r/7/)

Comment: Thank you. And can I maintain vertically centered text?

Answer (score 1):

`float: left` on your image is the way to go.

http://jsfiddle.net/bhu4p04r/2/

Or another alternative (to keep the text centered)

http://jsfiddle.net/Lbbt1uy8/

What is important to know is that `vertical-align` uses `line-height` not `height` to center something vertically.

Comment: Excellent! And now that the image is floated, how do I center my text again?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Yeah but if he removes the `<br>`, all text would be on the same line (because `img` is inline by default).

Comment: I missunderstood the question.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Ok, if you want to center your text there may be a better alternative (cleaner).

Comment: Added another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `<p>` elements instead of `</br>` on your text and add `align` attribute to your image like this:

```
<div class="medium-12 columns"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/75/90" align="left"/><p>1</p><p>2</p><p>3</p></div>
```

Here [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pjvtv376/2/)

Answer (score 0):

you had lots errors on the syntax
and you should wrap each element and assign them with separate CSS codes

HTML:

```
<div class="medium-12 columns">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/75/90"></img>
</div>

<div id="txt">
1<br>2<br>3<br>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.medium-12 {
    min-width:75px;
    height:90px;
    margin-right:30px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

#txt {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```